# Python array[0:1] not the same as array[0]

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I'm using Python to split a string of 2 bytes `b'\x01\x00'`. The string of bytes is stored in a variable called `flags`.

Why when I say `flags[0]` do I get `b'\x00'` but when I say `flags[0:1]` I get the expected answer of `b'\x01'`.

Should both of these operations not be exactly the same?

What I did:

```
>>> flags = b'\x01\x00'
>>> flags[0:1]
b'\x01'
>>> bytes(flags[0])
b'\x00'
```

Comment: No, slicing is not the same thing as indexing.

Comment: I thought, array[0:1] was the same as array[0] because it's inclusive of the 0th index and exclusive of the 1st index.

Comment: When you say `flags[0]` you'd get `1`, not `b'\x00'`.

Comment: Well, in case of byte strings in Python 2, I'd say a slice of length 1 should be exactly the same as indexing. And it is, if I test it.

Comment: Sorry again! You're correct, I was printing bytes(flags[0])

Comment: Umm... On Py2, `flags[0]` and `flags[0:1]` would return the same thing, `'\x01'`. I have no idea why you would think `flags[0]` would produce `\x00`. On Py 3, with true `bytes` objects, they would differ; indexing `bytes` gets `int` values from 0 to 255 inclusive, so `flags[0]` would get `1`, while slicing returns new `bytes` objects, so `flags[0:1]` would get `b'\x01'`. Side-note: `flags[0:1]` is better expressed as just `flags[:1]`; leaving the start index empty means "from start of sequence" here (if step is negative, it means "from end of sequence"), so the `0` is redundant.

Comment: @Francis: that is something *entirely different*, that is a new `bytes` object of length 1, pre-filled with `0x00` bytes.

Comment: @Francis: `bytes(flags[0])` is extra confusing, because `flags[0]` returns `1`, and the `bytes` constructor interprets `int` arguments as "create a zeroed out `bytes` object of that length", so `bytes(flags[0])` is equivalent to `bytes(1)`, which constructs `b'\x00'`.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3, `bytes` is a sequence type containing *integers* (each in the range 0 - 255) so indexing to a specific index gives you an integer.

And just like slicing a list produces a new list object for the slice, so does slicing a `bytes` object produce a new `bytes` instance. And the representation of a `bytes` instance tries to show you a `b'...'` literal syntax with the integers represented as either printable ASCII characters or an applicable escape sequence when the byte isn't printable. All this is great for developing but may hide the fact that bytes are really a sequence of integers.

However, you will still get the *same piece of information*; `flags[0:1]` is a one-byte long `bytes` value with the `\x01` byte in it, and `flags[0]` will give you the integer `1`:

```
>>> flags = b'\x01\x00'
>>> flags[0]
1
>>> flags[0:1]
b'\x01'
```

What you **really** did was not use `flags[0]`, you used `bytes(flags[0])` instead. Passing in a single integer to the `bytes()` type creates a new `bytes` object of the specified length, pre-filled with `\x00` bytes:

```
>>> flags[0]
1
>>> bytes(1)
b'\x00'
```

Since `flags[0]` produces the integer 1, you told `bytes()` to return a new bytes value of length 1, filled with `\x00` bytes.

From the [`bytes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> Bytes objects are immutable sequences of single bytes.
>
> [...]
>
> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text, bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers, with each value in the sequence restricted such that `0 <= x < 256`.
>
> [...]
>
> In addition to the literal forms, bytes objects can be created in a number of other ways:
>
> - **A zero-filled bytes object of a specified length: `bytes(10)`**

Bold emphasis mine.

If you wanted to create a new `bytes` object with that one byte in it, you'll need to put the integer value in a list first:

```
>>> bytes([flags[0]])
b'\x01'
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should get the same thing. In both cases `b'\x01'`. `flags` is probably not what you think it is.

```
>>> flags = b'\x01\x00'
>>> flags[0]
'\x01'
>>> flags[0:1]
'\x01'
```

Comment: This only applies to Python 2, which will treat `flags` as a `str`. Python 3 behaves differently, treating `flags` as an instance of `bytes`.

Comment: The OP is on Python 3 (otherwise they would have a `repr` with a `b` prefix), so no, not the same thing at all.